# Criar array dinâmicamente javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Eu quero fazer uma coisa mas não sei se é possivel, vamos a minha idéia.

Suponhamos que eu tenha uma pagina chamada `index.html` dentro dela tem um código javascript que recebe os dados de um select que esta em outra pagina chamada select.php, eu preciso que a pagina index.html receba esses dados da pagina php e crie uns arrays dinâmicos para cada registro recebido e exiba eles separadamente em um log do browser.

Exemplo:

```
[0][joão][10][São Paulo]

[1][Pedro][10][Bahia]
```

Comment: Podes explicar ou mostrar o código de _"recebe os dados de um select que esta em outra pagina"_?

Comment: Então, a questão é essa, eu só encontrei codigo que envia o valor do php para outra pagina, mas não o inverso. Eu preciso por exemplo, enviar via GET o nome do usuarioo e a pagina que rodar em segundo plano recebe e daa o select e envia todos os registros para a pagina em primeiro plano que vai criando o arrays e exibindo no log

Comment: Dá uma olhada na pergunta e respostas que marquei. Isso vai ajudar-te muito, se não resolver o problema por completo. Depois se tiveres alguma parte mais específica que precise de apoio faz outra pergunta ou pergunta aqui.

Comment: Então, não é bem isso que eu preciso, mas vou abrir outra pergunta pois eu tive uma nova ideia